# Cannot find protocol declaration for RKObjectLoaderDelegate xCode 4.6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, restkit

I am facing a RestKit error while implementing iOS application. Telling Cannot find protocol declaration for `RKObjectLoaderDelegate` or `RKRequestDelegate`.
And if I add `#import <RKObjectLoader.h>` it tells file not found.

How could I solve this? Is there anything missing?

I am using Restkit 0.20.0 and i imported Restkit using the following guide https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-in-Xcode-4.x

and i am getting use of undeclared identifier on `RKURL`. and i am importing `#import <Restkit\Restkit.h>` in the header file of each view.

my class implements the following `@interface TrackingMapViewCOntroller : UIViewController <MapViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, RKObjectLoaderDelegate>`

Answer (score 1):

your class implements RKObjectLoaderDelegate?
Like:
@interface RestKitConfiguration : RKObjectManager

If it helps this is the wiki page on github:
https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki

Can you add more details? 
What kind of RestKit version are you using (0.10.0 / 0.20.0)?
How you imported RestKit in your project? Git submodule?

**Edit:**

> There is no RKURL in 0.20.0 version of restkit, now it use AFNetworking; 
>   make attention of what kind of tutorial you use, there
>   is a lot of confusion right now. I have encountered such similar
>   mistakes/errors about old version guides.
>
> Read here for more infos: [Upgrading from v0.10.x to v0.20.0][1]
>
> [1]:
>   https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Upgrading-from-v0.10.x-to-v0.20.0

Comment: thanks for writing, i updated the question, please check it.

Comment: I just updated the answer, i hope it helps you!

Comment: Thanks. But i removed and reinstalled restkit 0.10.2 and that worked for me without any changes or suffering.

Comment: I actually use only the 0.10.x in working projects too, but i want to learn the 0.20.x innovations for my next projects. If the answer is correct flag it, please. Good luck!

Comment: This issue seems to be not just related to RestKit. I am getting this error for my won protocol. Any thoughts ?